# Acceder a datos en React

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Buen día, tengo el siguiente Json.

Cómo puedo acceder a cada dato de la lista y sumar las unidades cuando el nombre del producto coincida?

```
 const [ventasFiltradas, setVentasFiltradas] = useState([]);

 const total = ventasFiltradas.reduce(
      (valor, elemento) => valor + elemento.total,0);

      

totalUnidades = ventasFiltradas.reduce(
      (valor, elemento) => {
        return valor + elemento['lista'].reduce(
          (a,b) => a + parseInt(b['unidades']
        ), 0)
      }, 0
    );

<TableCell>$ { totalUnidades }</TableCell>

---
[
  {
    "id": "3WzFN",
    "cliente": "1",
    "lista": [
      {
        "unidades": "2",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 1",
        "peso": "2"
      },
    ],
    "nombre": "Vendedor 3",
    "total": 100
  },
  {
    "id": "6Zls",
    "cliente": "2",
    "lista": [
      {
        "unidades": "4",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 2",
        "peso": "2"
      },
      {
        "unidades": "4",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 1",
        "peso": "2"
     }
   ],
   "nombre":"Vendedor1",
   "total":550
    }, 
   {
     "id":"U2HX",
     "cliente":"3",
     "lista":[
       {
        "unidades":"2",
        "precio":"25",
        "subtotal":100,
        "producto":"Producto1",
        "peso":"2"
      },
      {
        "unidades": "3",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 3",
        "peso": "2"
    }
    ],"
           nombre":"Vendedor2",
           "total":600
     }, 
    {
      "id":"aJixp",
      "cliente":"4",
       "lista":[
          {
            "unidades":"2",
            "precio":"25",
            "subtotal":100,
            "producto":"Producto1",
            "peso":"2"
      }
    ],
    "nombre": "Vendedor 3",
    "total": 220
  }
]
```

El total puedo sumarlo sin problemas, pero no puedo hacer que sume las unidades solo cuando el nombre del producto coincida (cualquier nombre de Producto).

Ya puedo sumar las unidades pero me las suma todas sin importar el nombre del producto, lo que quiero es que si un nombre de producto coincide (cualquier nombre) me realice la suma de las unidades.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrías mostrar un pequeño ejemplo de los datos de entrada y el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: Hola, espero obtener:  Producto 1= 10. Producto 2 = 8. Producto 3 = 3.  Quiero sumar unidades si el producto coincide.

Comment: Hola @CarlosJurado! Creo que a tu JSON le falta o sobra una comilla, o algo. podes fijarte por favor?

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como:

Probablemente haya formas más fáciles de escribir esto, pero el código funciona para tu propósito.

```js
const lista = [
  {
    "id": "3WzFN",
    "cliente": "1",
    "lista": [
      {
        "unidades": "2",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 1",
        "peso": "2"
      },
    ],
    "nombre": "Vendedor 3",
    "total": 100
  },
  {
    "id": "6Zls",
    "cliente": "2",
    "lista": [
      {
        "unidades": "4",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 2",
        "peso": "2"
      },
      {
        "unidades": "4",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 1",
        "peso": "2"
     }
   ],
   "nombre":"Vendedor1",
   "total":550
    }, 
   {
     "id":"U2HX",
     "cliente":"3",
     "lista":[
       {
        "unidades":"2",
        "precio":"25",
        "subtotal":100,
        "producto":"Producto1",
        "peso":"2"
      },
      {
        "unidades": "3",
        "precio": "25",
        "subtotal": 100,
        "producto": "Producto 3",
        "peso": "2"
    }],
           "nombre":"Vendedor2",
           "total":600
     }, 
    {
      "id":"aJixp",
      "cliente":"4",
       "lista":[
          {
            "unidades":"2",
            "precio":"25",
            "subtotal":100,
            "producto":"Producto1",
            "peso":"2"
      }
    ],
    "nombre": "Vendedor 3",
    "total": 220
  }
];

const sumarLasUnidades = () => {
  const nuevaLista = [];
  lista.forEach((vendedor) => {
    vendedor.lista.forEach((producto) => {
      const existe = nuevaLista.filter(p=> p.nombre === producto.producto);
      if (existe.length) {
        const index = nuevaLista.indexOf(existe[0]);
        nuevaLista[index].unidades = nuevaLista[index].unidades + parseInt(producto.unidades);
      } else {
        nuevaLista.push({nombre: producto.producto, unidades: parseInt(producto.unidades)});
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(nuevaLista);
}

sumarLasUnidades();
```